# Using Facebook REST API to login, but meet 'Application does not have the capability to make this API call'

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-rest-api

I'm a newbee on facebook development and I'm trying to do some basic feature on FB, just post a message to wall and upload some picture. This feature would be integrated into a game.

Now the problem is I HAVE TO use the REST API to login, using the url and parameters below:

https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=facebook.auth.login&api_key=393870187360051&v=1.0&sig=d2985e6e3ac9fe3efe814d5c9c614f57&format=JSON&email=myfacebookaccount&password=mypassword

However I got the error 'Application does not have the capability to make this API call'

I have double checked that the FB app_key and account is correct, and the APP is bound to the account already.

I don't understand what that error message means. Do I miss something when calling the request? or this REST API is already deprecated? I doubt it because I find no reference about the METHOD facebook.auth.login on the official website now.

PS. I use the REST API in that way BECAUSE I must use some company internal API, which implements the login request like that above. If that method is already deprecated, I need to ask the guy to upgrade the API.

Thx so much

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/  The REST api is deprecated, so you should not be relying on it as methods could be fully removed at any point (if they haven't already been removed). If I was you I'd get the guy to upgrade!

Answer (score 0):

In case of someone who still need to play around with the Facebook legacy REST APIs, please take note that the REST API is not supported for newer Facebook app.

For details, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962108/facebook-app-with-rest-api).