# Facebook app with REST API

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-rest-api

Can I create a new Facebook app to use old REST api for user authentication. I would like to use the method auth.login for user authentication. Is it possible to use REST api with new facebook apps?

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook's legacy REST API does not work for new Facebook apps registered **[after Apr/2013](http://www.webpronews.com/facebook-retires-the-rest-api-for-new-apps-2013-04)**. However, REST API is still supported for existing Facebook app created before Apr/2013.

You will get "*Error 3 : Application does not have the capability to make this API call*" when trying to access REST API from the new Facebook app.

For newer Facebook app, please use Graph API to achieve the similar functionality as in the legacy REST API.

Answer (score 0):

The REST API is deprecated now. Blog post here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/616/

Comment: Its only deprecated. That doesn't mean that they removed the api. I want to know whether new apps can use them for login. When i used REST api in one app its responding, but not able to login evenif i give all the parameters.